# Matching Rando bag and seat-attached saddle bag?

Tags: bags, randonneuring

What companies make matching sets of rando bags (with a clear map pocket and opens toward the rider) and seat mount saddle bags (not panniers) made from waxed canvas, duck cloth, or other non-synthetic material?

I've found only one http://www.acornbags.com that seems to have completely matching sets that meet my requirements. Are there other companies?  I've checked out velo orange but their offerings are poorly matched as they have 3-4 different brands which don't look great together and no larger saddle bags that match the one rando bag they offer. Zimbale bags looked promising, except their front rack bag doesn't have a map pocket and opens away from the rider...

I do have front and rear racks with a platform, I'd prefer not to have to rely on having the rear rack installed unless I plan on touring. So, I'd prefer that the saddle bag be seat/seatpost attached only.

Comment: A brand that comes to mind is Gilles Berthoud, take a look: http://www.wallbike.com/berthoud/handlebar-bags/berthoud-frontbags-basic . Possible problems: not cheap; not lightweight; not necessarily better than other options. But they're relatively famous for being long-lasting.

Comment: Acorn bags are worth the trouble and time it takes to order them. You can have my [Acorn tool roll](http://www.flickr.com/photos/neilfein/3408183394/) when you take it from from my cold, dead, gloved fingers.

Comment: Acorn look similar to [Carradice](http://www.carradice.co.uk/home) in style, and it looks like they're available from wallbike too.

Comment: Unfortunately, acorn bags doesn't have the rando bag available yet on their webstore.  So, I'm still looking for other options. However, I've sent them a request to be notified when that bag is available.

Comment: I'd also look at what [Rivendell](http://www.rivbike.com/Bike-Bags-s/37.htm) offers.

Comment: @Benzo - You could also set up a Google alert to crawl their site for you.

Comment: It looks like rivendell has a matching set, if you pick the Olive Sackville Barsack and an Olive Sackville SaddleSack. Unfortunately, I'm not going to use the Barsack since it wants to be bar mounted, and I want it to sit on top of my nitto campee racks. It doesn't have the straps to be mounted in that fasion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gilles Berthoud](http://www.wallbike.com/berthoud/handlebar-bags/berthoud-frontbags-basic) and [Acorn Bags](http://www.acornbags.com/) were the only matching sets I found that met the requirements of having both a rack mount frontbag and a rear seat only rear bag made from matching material.

Update 1/8/13: 
[Swift Polaris bags](http://builtbyswift.com/) can be paired with their saddle bag to match.

Comment: I did manage to get a pair of the Acorn Bags, but they do seem very hard to get due to limited production. I ordered one the minute they went on sale and 30 seconds later they were all sold out.

Comment: Thanks to heltonbiker for the link to Gilles Berthound. Those bags would have worked, but they were a lot more expensive than anything else I considered.

Answer (score 1):

The [Brooks Cornwall handlebar bag](http://www.wallbike.com/brooks/handlebar-bags/brooks-cornwall-handlebar-bag) matches your needs, in leather, and in multiple colors.[image: Brooks Cornwall handlebar bag]

Matched with [the Glenbrook Saddle bag](http://www.wallbike.com/brooks/saddlebags/brooks-glenbrook-saddlebag),
[image: the Glenbrook Saddle bag]

or [the Brooks Challenge Roll-up Tool bag](http://www.wallbike.com/brooks/saddlebags/brooks-challenge-tool-bag),
[image: Challenge roll up]

it would be pretty nice.

All of these, along with a multitude of other brands and styles can be found on [the Wallbike.com site](http://wallbike.com), or your LBS can order them for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't see these as matching.  They have different colors of leather it looks. I'm very specific about matching materials, which has made my search difficult for a good pair.

Comment: Like I said, they are available in *different* color options. These pictures are of the main image, which isn't necessarily the matching color for each. That's why I linked the site, and told you to go look.